# Firefox - re-attach Developer Tools to main window

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

Since it is possible to "pull out" the Developer Tools, so they appear as an own window, 
I would like to know if there is a way to restore the original form of the Firefox Developer Tools, so it shows below the website in the active Firefox window instead of as an independent one.

edit: I am currently running v22.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the button you want - circled in red. It toggles the firebug window in/out of the main window.

[image: Firebug]

Comment: Thanks for the help, seems the skin i use did not cover these, all the top-right-corner buttons are not visible. [view here](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-19955096/unsichtbar.jpg.html)

Comment: You are welcome. It is surprising that the three buttons are dark grey in colour - not easy to spot!